# How to add a column to items in an array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a Json object coming from a backend server  called `Data` like this:

```
[{
  "categoryName": "Google",
  "id": "58591d2b7672d99910497bec",
  "clientId": "585808f6737f6aad1985eab2"
}, {
  "categoryName": "Microsoft",
  "id": "58591d3d7672d99910497bee",
  "clientId": "585808f6737f6aad1985eab2"
}, "3", {
  "categoryName": "Yahoo",
  "id": "58591d4c7672d99910497bef",
  "clientId": "585808f6737f6aad1985eab2"
}, {
  "categoryName": "Msn",
  "id": "585d25f6ae4b2ecb056bc514",
  "clientId": "585808f6737f6aad1985eab2"
}]
```

and I would like to add a column (property?) to each row like this:

```
[{
  "categoryName": "Google",
  "id": "58591d2b7672d99910497bec",
  "clientId": "585808f6737f6aad1985eab2",
  "new column": ""
}, {
  "categoryName": "Microsoft",
  "id": "58591d3d7672d99910497bee",
  "clientId": "585808f6737f6aad1985eab2",
  "new column": ""
}, "3", {
  "categoryName": "Yahoo",
  "id": "58591d4c7672d99910497bef",
  "clientId": "585808f6737f6aad1985eab2",
  "new column": ""
}, {
  "categoryName": "Msn",
  "id": "585d25f6ae4b2ecb056bc514",
  "clientId": "585808f6737f6aad1985eab2",
  "new column": ""
}]
```

Does anyone how I can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could use javascript's map function to add the new property to each object. but why would you do it if it's going to be an empty string anyway?

Comment: why is there a "3" suddenly?

Comment: It is not going to stay empty, of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
data.forEach(function(e){
  if (typeof e === "object" ){
    e["new column"] = ""
  }
});
```

Needs that typeof check because of that weird `3` in the middle.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this:

```
const arr = data.map(x => Object.assign({}, data, { "new column": "" }))
```

Comment: This still needs to handle that weird "3".  But +1 for not mutating the original data and for using the appropriate verb, `map`.

Comment: Here is my code. The json file is not showing any added column ... :(this.category.find({where: {clientId: this.userApi.getCurrentId()}}).subscribe((data) => {
            this.categories = data;
            console.log("type of this.categories: " + isArray(this.categories));
            const arr  = data.map(x => Object.assign({}, data, { "new column": "3" }));

            console.log ("data:" + JSON.stringify(data));
         }, err => {
            console.log(err);
        });